# Check if any element in a NodeList has a specific class using ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, ecmascript-6

I want to check if any element in a NodeList has a specific class.

For example, with jQuery I just do something like:

```
//if any .item element has active class, return true
var isActive = $(".item").hasClass("active");
```

Only with Javascript I could do, but with a slightly longer code:

```js
var isActive = false;
var items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("item"));

items.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if(item.className.indexOf('active') > 0) {
 isActive = true;
  }
});

alert(isActive);
```

```html
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item active">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
```

How can I do this with ES6? There is a helper for selectors?

Thanks!

Comment: "There is a helper for selectors?" No, there isn't. Selectors are a part of Web APIs, JS has no support for selectors.

Comment: ES6 (ES2015 now) really doesn't have anything to do with DOM operations or CSS selectors; those are browser environment features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with ES2015, but you can use `document.querySelector()` much like the basic jQuery API:

```
 var isActive = document.querySelector(".item.active") != null;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("item")).some(({classList}) =>
   classList.contains('active'))
```

is probably the best ES6 can give you, which is essentially the same as your code above.

Comment: I think `el => el.classList.…` is more idiomatic than destructuring here

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need ES6 to do the same thing in vanilla JS.

```
// jQuery
var isActive = $(".item").hasClass("active"); 

// Plain JavaScript
var isActive = document.querySelector('.item').classList.contains('active');
```

Comment: will this work with `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

You can [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on a nodelist and return the first true result.

```
const activeEl = Array.prototype.find.call (items, item => item.classList.contains('active'));
```